Deploy Codesys Project by copying files (projectarchive file?) to Berghoff PLC Controller
Is it possible to deploy the CodeSys Project (appliation code not runtime) by copying files to the Berghoff PLC Controller?
I know we can deploy the application/project from the Codesys IDE or thru the Automation Server. But we are trying to deploy the code to our device manually without have a Windows Server running the Codesys IDE or having to upload our project to the Automation Server.
I have tried reading the /etc/init.d/codesyscontrol script (which does not support loading new application). I have also tried the deployment thru the IDE and thru the Automation Server.

If what you want is to deployed using a script automatically without interacting with the GUI, you can use the ScriptEngine Python API to do so, though you'd still need Codesys IDE installed.

Yes, i saw the documents for that as well. No, we want to be able to deploy a Codesys application to a PLC without the IDE, because we are running only Linux boxes. Codesys IDE is only supported on windows.

While still probably not what you want, a light VM that runs when deploying is also a possible option, though an annoying one.

We were able to deploy the application by copying the Application.app, Application.crc and the visu folder to the appropriate folder on the PLC.
For us this folder was /home/plc/applications/PlcLogic/Application/ but this would probably depend on your PLC vendor.
Note, this was not the first deployment, but only updates after a deployment.
